# how avoid excess serialization for Google page speed?

Tags: html, seo

I have noticed by Google's page speed an error in experimental rules, as avoid excess serialization.
https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/#url=http_3A_2F_2Fim.7arena.com&mobile=false

Anyone can say, how solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By serving content from multiple hostnames: http://www.faresweb.net/tutorial/web-site-optimization-avoid-excess-serialization

Comment: Well, it seems this rule was added recently and is still very experimental - maybe it's just working incorrectly.